# MongoDB find query takes too much time on a database of 200MB+

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mern

In my database there is a createdAt column. What I am trying to do is fetch all the data of a specific month given a current month and year. What would be the most fastest and efficient way to do it?

This is my code:

```
module.exports.fetchVotings = (year, month) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const days_count = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        console.log(days_count);

        // get data of a month of the given year of createdAt
        let res = await mongoose.connection.db.collection('votings').find({
            "createdAt": {
                "$gte": new Date(year, month - 1, 1),
                "$lt": new Date(year, month, days_count)
            }
        }).sort({ createdAt: 1 }).toArray();

        resolve(res);
    })
}
```

Comment: Creating index on the field used in the query filter and/or sort operation can help with performance.

Comment: why are you doing `-1` to the current month? this will give you 2 months worth of data

Answer (score 0):

in your query, you can do some things that might be  helpful for you
like

1. you can create an index on your collection.
2. if you using sorting on **createdAt** as 1 then might be you not need to sort your data.because it's already sorted.
3. you can use projection in your query to remove unnecessary data(which is not required) in the result.